# where clause does not work in GAE datastore viewer

Tags: google-cloud-datastore

I am new to GAE, please excuse for being naive.

datastore viewer query with where clause returns "No results in Empty namespace.".

For instance:
select * from GaeUser 
returns all the entires.

Something like,
select * from GaeUser where firstName = 'somename' 
or
select * from GaeUser where dayOfBirth = 5
returns nothing but the message No results in empty namespace.

I am expecting some pointers on how to debug this.

Thanks for reading this!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply you just wrote an incorrect/misspelled query.

Note that GAE datastore is schema-less. Writing a query for a nonexisting entity or for a nonexisting property or specifying a filter condition where you use an incorrect data type will not result in error but rather in an empty result.

Being schema-less also means that 2 entities of the same kind might have the same property with different types. For example you might have a `Person` entity with an `age` property of type `int` and another `Person` with an `age` property of type `String`. Obviously in this case if you write something like

```
select * from Person where age='5'
```

will not return the person who has `age=5` property having `int` type.

So just simply double check the names and types of the entity and properties and try again.

**Another important note:**

Properties are *indexed* by default. This means when saving an entity, index records for an indexed property will automatically be created and saved, this allows you to find this entity by this indexed property. Properties can be made *unindexed*. When you save an entity with an unindexed property, index records will not be saved (or if there were any, they will be removed) for this unindexed property and you will not be able to query/find this entity by this unindexed property.

Comment: Hi.. Thank you for the response.
I certainly cross checked the spellings and it seems to be alright.
firstName
value: Stephen
type: String

Comment: There might be that you try to search by *unindexed* properties. See my edited answer.

Comment: thank you very much. Yes indeed, the property I was querying wasn't indexed.